# The result of Linux time command

Tags: linux, time

I got a result from linux time command.

```
real    119m10.626s
user    133m0.952s
 sys    20m32.155s
```

From the information I searched, it seems that user+sys should less than real, but it is not the case here.
Does somebody know why?

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple CPUs.

A multi-threaded application can run simultaneously on multiple CPU cores, (and thus accumulating CPU Time as multiples of real time)